# Token Based Authenication with Node/Express

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, json-web-token

I’m a little confused as to how JWT authentication works. Once a user is able to log in, my express server is responding with a token, which I store on the client side in local storage. With every request, I send that token. My question is, how do I limit a user to see his/her specific data (e.g., user profile)? Is the token alone able to determine which user is requesting the user data on the server side or would i have to send the username along with the token? Is this secure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JWT token will contains 3 parts, one of them called a payload and you will use it to store the user's id when he logs in. When the user sends a request with his token you will decode it and grab the id from the payload and then with a query to your database you can get the user's profile.

> how do I limit a user to see his/her specific data (e.g., user
>   profile)?

If you get the id from the token's payload then you can compare it with the id of the profile that the user wants to see, if they are the same then it means that he wants to see his profile.

> Is the token alone able to determine which user is requesting the user
>   data on the server side or would I have to send the username along
>   with the token?

No need for username, the token alone is sufficient because it identifies the user.

> Is this secure?

Read this: http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/ there are other opinions of course, try implementing best practices and I think you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Exactly what I was looking for. I’ve read that article previously, and while I don’t disagree, the author fails to provide a feasible alternative.